# Fill String Array With ListBox Selected Items in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox that has X amount (Varies from 9 - 90) of items. I'm trying to populate (On a button click) a string array with the items that are selected in the ListBox. Here is what I have so far

```
private void generateTam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sCombinedTam = "";
        String sTamResponseStart = "Dear $contacts.name.first,@\n@\nYour request has been received and completed.@\nThe following actions were taken:@\n";
        String sTamResponseEnd = "Thank you for choosing %company%, and have a great day!!@\n@\n$incidents.assigned.acct_id@\n%company%";

        sTamResponseStart = sTamResponseStart.Replace("@\n", System.Environment.NewLine); //Replaces token @\n with NewLine
        //Gets Actions Selected, Sends to Array
        String[] sActionItemsSelected = new String[actionsListBox.Items.Count];
        for (int x = 0; x < actionsListBox.Items.Count; ++x)
        {
            if (actionsListBox.GetSelected(x) == true)
            {
                actionsListBox.Items.CopyTo(sActionItemsSelected, 0);

            }
        }
        //Gets Profiles Selected, Sends to Array
        String[] sProfileItemsSelected = new String[profilesListBox.Items.Count];
        for (int x = 0; x < profilesListBox.Items.Count; ++x)
        {
            if (profilesListBox.GetSelected(x) == true)
            {
                profilesListBox.Items.CopyTo(sProfileItemsSelected, x);
            }
            else if (profilesListBox.GetSelected(x) == false)
            {
                sProfileItemsSelected[x] = "";
            }
        }
        //Combines strings for end response
        for (int i = 0; i < sActionItemsSelected.Length; ++i)
        {
            sCombinedTam = sCombinedTam + sActionItemsSelected[i] + "@\n";
        }
        sCombinedTam = sCombinedTam.Replace("@\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
        sTamResponseEnd = sTamResponseEnd.Replace("@\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
        sCombinedTam = sTamResponseStart + sCombinedTam + sTamResponseEnd;
        notesTextBox.Text = sCombinedTam;

        //Outputs ENTIRE index ListBoxes not just selected items.

    }
```

The problem comes at the end, instead of setting `notesTextBox.Text` to the combination string with only the ListBox Selected Items it sets it to the combination string with EVERY ListBox option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected output for `sCombinedTam`?

Comment: @jhyap
Something like this 
`Dear $contacts.name.first,@\n@\nYour request has been received and completed.@\nThe following actions were taken:@\n

[Insert Action Selected 1]
[Insert Action Selected 2]
...
[Insert Action Selected 90]

Thank you for choosing %company%, and have a great day!!@\n@\n$incidents.assigned.acct_id@\n%company%
`

Where @\n is replaced with a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ListBox.SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get all selected items in a single string, separated by the newline string *(you can remove the last* `for` *loop, as well as some of your other code)*.

You can cast the collection of selected items back to whatever type they are; in your case, a string.

```
var selectedItems =
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: Doing `sActionItemsSelected = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, actionsListBox.SelectedItems);` Returns the following

`System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection`

Not the string like I was expecting.

Comment: The window this is contained in is WPF but the application itself is WinForms.

Comment: Yes just a collection of strings.

Comment: It looks like I am using WinForms controls as I look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using linq

```
items = (from string s in listBox1.SelectedItems select s).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim selectedItems As String() = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of String).ToArray
```